# how to edit delete data row in gridview where data come from database using binding function in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need a little help.
I am binding data from database to gridview in asp.net c#, my problem is that when I add, edit,delete and select button in every row then when I click on edit or delete button then no any action perform. can anyone help me.Thank you in advance.

here is source code for that

```
    string str = "select max(trans_id) from purchase";

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = c.FetchData(str);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = c.FetchData("select * from pur_trans where trans_id=" + ddltansid.SelectedValue.ToString() + "".Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        GridView1.Visible = false;

    }![enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the events for edit and delete. Please go through below given link and read all the steps given into it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667599/Add-Edit-update-Delete-gridview